# create an HTML link for iframe by date

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I have an event list in an iframe and wants always the current event is displayed on the page above. For old events I would have to scroll down for newer upwards. How can I create an HTML link, which then triggers the corresponding anchor in the list. The name of the anchor is, for example "12_2014".

Comment: `<a href="#12-2014">12_2014</a>`

Comment: Something like this sounds like it would work: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3

Comment: Are you trying to trigger from outside the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try: May be this could help:
it's just a prototype:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#12-2014">12_2014</a>
<div id="12-2014">
    Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test ContentTest Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content
</div>
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/35UuB/)